# Is it possible for a bug in the source code ports of the network(TCP/IP)?

Tags: services, tcp-ip

That may not be a logical question.
But I would like to understand this.

Any service that provides services on the Internet
Has a set of specifications and ports based on standards and tasks.
To launch these services, a set of code is defined and placed in the operating system kernel and runs in the background.

I mean, every service has a port
For example service ssh, https, FTP,...
These services have ports that require ports when connected.
 Every mechanism runs on a computer with some source code. it's true?
I want to say that the source code written to create network ports can cause security problems and get bugs and exploits?

Because there are always bugs and security problems in the service.
So it can be said that source code has bugs to create ports!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking about ports? Source code? Compiled source code? Or bugs?

Comment: about ports.
I want to understand how ports are defined and Can there be a risk to network security?
Example: Security Vulnerabilities ports(Source code port for TCP/IP stack ).

Comment: An exploit can be executed on the remote host via Secure Shell (SSH).
with being bug in the source code(ssh).
Does An exploit can be bug on source code ports(TCP/IP stack)?

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 2 bind;man 7 raw;man socket`. Also read the "SEE ALSO" recommendations.

When a server starts, it creates a socket, and configures the socket to read from a specific port.

Other systems may send TCP/IP packets to the server, on the specified port.

It's up to the server to decide what to do with the data.

There is a list of well-known ports that most servers follow, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_ports  but it's voluntary and configurable. For example, a web server listening on port 80 is no different than a web server listening on port 8080, except that it opens a non-privileged port.

A server is not "placed in the operating system kernel", it's run a a regular program. Additional privileges are necessary if the server wants to open a "privileged" port (1-1023), but well-written servers relinquish the privilege after opening a socket on the privileged port.